# Scipy not solving integral with big numbers

Tags: python, scipy, quad

Here is the simple code that I'm trying to run:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

def integrand1(p, n, x, E, S):
    return (p**(x+1))*((1-p)**(n-x))
def integrand2(p, n, x, E, S):
    return (p**(x))*((1-p)**(n-x))

E = 0.789
S = 0.733
n = 8928  # This number is already too big to compute. If you change it to just 89 works.
x = 2325  # This number is already too big to compute. If you change it to just 23 works.

I1 = quad(integrand1, 1-E, S, args=(n, x, E, S))
I2 = quad(integrand2, 1-E, S, args=(n, x, E, S))
I = I1[0]/I2[0]
print(I)
```

It is basically the quotient of two integrals. It works fine for values of `n` and `x`  up to the hundreds. After that, in the thousands and tens of thousands, the result starts to go to zero, which is not correct. Since there is exponentiation with a high power, I guess that there is some overflow or underflow somewhere, but since there is no message, I can't discover what is wrong. Does anyone have a clue on what may be wrong?

Comment: Not overflow, but underflow. Computations are done with IEEE 754 arithmetic, which has finite precision, and bounded exponents. For small p and large n, p**n can't be represented and is replaced by 0. You may try to manipulate your integral so that it becomes manageable (change of variable, factor out something...), but here I'm not sure it would change anything. Another option: compute exactly your integral (maybe with special functions, here I'm not sure but there could be an incomplete beta function).

Comment: Recommended reading before doing anything with floating point: http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf Also some very good things there: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: Thanks for your help. The resources that you pointed out seems to be very relevant, not only for this problem, but for my education as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

SciPy has a private quadrature function (which will become public in time) that can compute the log of the integral from the log of the integrand, which helps avoid overflow and underflow.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate._tanhsinh import _tanhsinh

def log_integrand1(p, n, x, E, S):
    return ((x+1) * np.log(p)) + ((n-x) * np.log1p(-p))

def log_integrand2(p, n, x, E, S):
    return (x * np.log(p)) + ((n-x) * np.log1p(-p))

E = 0.789
S = 0.733
n = 8928
x = 2325

logI1 = _tanhsinh(log_integrand1, 1-E, S, args=(n, x, E, S), log=True)
logI2 = _tanhsinh(log_integrand2, 1-E, S, args=(n, x, E, S), log=True)
logI = logI1.integral - logI2.integral

print(np.exp(logI))
# 0.26047032474789905
```

Comment: Logarithms are a good workaround for computation on very large and very small values.